# Pairing rows from two tables and show only content of first table if it does not exist in second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, left-join

This is a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63903753/sql-server-2014-pairing-rows-from-2-tables-based-on-values-coming-from-a-third) from which I had an answer.

I'm still trying to pair records from 2 tables if they match. But I now need to see the record in the first table even if the second record does not exist.

The first table #T1 contains events that always comes before events in the second table #T2. But this time a matching event in #T2 may never comes in.

A third table #E contains records that defines for an event the values that comes in #T1 and #T2 respectively.

To paraphrase the answer to my previous question:

Logic is as follows - for each row in T1 ...

- Find the matching rows in T2, where 'matching' means a) same VehicleId, b) same EventId, c) EventValue is limited by possibilities in #E, and d) occurs after the event in T1
- Find the first (minimum) timestamp from T2 for each row in T1
- Calculate EventDelay as the times between the two timestamps

And now the last requirement is:

- If there is no matching row in T2, return only the data about T1.

This seems as easy as using a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN but it does not work.

New sample data below and attempt for a a new query that still returns 2 records instead of 3.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 
(
    EventTimestamp DateTime, 
    VehicleId int, 
    EventId varchar(50), 
    EventValue varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE #T2 
(
    EventTimestamp DateTime, 
    VehicleId int, 
    EventId varchar(50), 
    EventValue varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE #E 
(
     EventId varchar(50), 
     FirstValue int, 
     LastValue varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO #T1(EventTimestamp, VehicleId , EventId, EventValue)
VALUES (GETDATE(), 1, 'TwigStatus', '12'),
       (GETDATE(), 2, 'SafeProtectEvent', '5'),
       (DATEADD(minute, 10, GETDATE()), 1, 'TwigStatus', '12')

INSERT INTO #T2(EventTimestamp, VehicleId , EventId, EventValue)
VALUES (DATEADD(second, 30, GETDATE()), 1, 'TwigStatus', '7'),
       (DATEADD(second, 30, GETDATE()), 2, 'SafeProtectEvent', '6')

INSERT INTO #E(EventId, FirstValue, LastValue)
VALUES ('TwigStatus', '12', '7'),
       ('SafeProtectEvent', '5', '6')

; WITH ord AS
        (SELECT     t1.VehicleId, 
                    t1.EventTimestamp AS first, 
                    t2.EventTimestamp AS last,
                    t1.EventId, 
                    t2.EventValue,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.VehicleId, t1.EventTimestamp, t1.EventId ORDER BY t1.EventTimestamp) AS rn
            FROM    #T1 AS t1
                    LEFT JOIN #T2 AS t2 ON t1.VehicleID = t2.VehicleID AND t1.EventID = t2.EventID
                    LEFT JOIN #E AS e ON t1.EventId = e.EventId 
                                      AND t1.EventValue = e.FirstValue
                                      AND t2.eventId = e.EventId 
                                      AND t2.EventValue = e.LastValue
            WHERE   t2.EventTimestamp > t1.EventTimestamp
        )

    SELECT      VehicleId, first, last, EventId, EventValue,
                DATEDIFF(second, first, last) AS EventDelay
        FROM    ord
        WHERE   rn = 1

DROP TABLE #E;
DROP TABLE #T1;
DROP TABLE #T2;
```

Comment: Your CTE's `where` clause references a column on the right side of a `left outer join` without allowing for `null`. That converts the `outer join` to an `inner join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CTE looks like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM #t1 t1
LEFT JOIN #t2 t2 ON ...
LEFT JOIN #E  e  ON ...
WHERE t2.EventTimestamp > t1.EventTimestamp
```

Move the condition in the `where` clause to the `on` clause of the `left join`. Otherwise, it becomes mandatory, and rows that have no match in `t2` are filered out - because their `EventTimestamp` is `null`, and hence do not fulfill the inequality condition.

```
WITH ord AS
        (SELECT     t1.VehicleId, 
                    t1.EventTimestamp AS first, 
                    t2.EventTimestamp AS last,
                    t1.EventId, 
                    t2.EventValue,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.VehicleId, t1.EventTimestamp, t1.EventId ORDER BY t1.EventTimestamp) AS rn
            FROM    #T1 AS t1
                    LEFT JOIN #T2 AS t2 ON t1.VehicleID = t2.VehicleID 
                                        AND t1.EventID = t2.EventID 
                                        AND t2.EventTimestamp > t1.EventTimestamp
                    LEFT JOIN #E AS e ON t1.EventId = e.EventId 
                                      AND t1.EventValue = e.FirstValue
                                      AND t2.eventId = e.EventId 
                                      AND t2.EventValue = e.LastValue
        )

    SELECT      VehicleId, first, last, EventId, EventValue,
                DATEDIFF(second, first, last) AS EventDelay
        FROM    ord
        WHERE   rn = 1
```